# Write simple image uploader plugin for jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been learning some jquery for while, now I want to author some plugins just for fun and I wrote this extrelemy plugin for upload image, my question is: Am I in the right way?

The plugin itself:

```
$.fn.imageUploader = function (options) {

var options = $.extend(options);
var url = options.url;    

this.click(function myfunction() {
    var imgId = this.id;
    var jqFrmId = "#Frm" + this.id;
    var fileId = "File" + this.id;
    var jqFileId = "#" + fileId;

    //use of title attribute for extra data
    var data = $(this).attr("title");

    //append a form for each file upload
    $("body").append("<form id='Frm" + this.id + "' action='" + url + "?data=" + data + "'  method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
    //append a input file
    $(jqFrmId).append("<input type='file' id='" + fileId + "' name='" + fileId + "' style='display: none;' />");

    $(jqFileId).change(function () {
        $(jqFrmId).submit(); //upload image
        $("form").remove(jqFrmId);
    });

    $("form").ajaxForm({
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + imgId).attr("src", data); //shows image on callback
        }
    });

    $(jqFileId).click();

});
};
```

And how to call:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(".Image").imageUploader({ url: "Index/UploadImg" }); //or
        $("#ImageDetail").imageUploader({ url: "Index/UploadImg" });
    })
```

And Html page looks like this:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>                        
                    <img alt="Front" title="Front" class="Image" id="ImageFront" src="~/Image/NoImage.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
                </td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>                        
                    <img alt="Detail" title="Detail" class="Image" id="ImageDetail" src="~/Image/NoImage.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>                
</table>
```

Comment: I would say no because your plugin doesn't return a jquery object. You should keep chaining!

Comment: Can You point me out how so? Thanks!

Comment: Look here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins   Basically, you would need something like: `return this.each(function(){this.on('click',function(){...})});`